# Dissolve a background drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to do something similar to this with the background image dissolving:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizonal">        
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm programmatically setting the background image like this:

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image)).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bg_image);
```

If I had to guess, I need to set the opacity of the layout as it's not the image that is dissolving but the layout surrounding it. I've searched and I think I need to use `setAlpha` but I don't want the entire image transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Gradient in XML resource.

> bg_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/blue"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

> activity_main.xml

Set Image on the background layout and on top of that set gradient.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_version">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Result

[image]